# On the commutativity of tensor product in $\mathscr{D}'$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, distribution-theory

Citing Wikipedia:

> Let $U\subseteq \mathbb {R} ^{m}$ and $V\subseteq \mathbb {R} ^{n}$ be open sets. Assume all vector spaces to be over the field $\mathbb {F}$, where
> $\mathbb{F} =\mathbb {R}$ or $\mathbb {C}$. For $f\in {\mathcal {D}}(U\times V)$ define for every $u \in U$ and every $v\in V$ the following functions:
> $$ {\begin{alignedat}{9}f_{u}:\,&V&&\to \,&&\mathbb {F} &&\quad {\text{ and }}\quad &&f^{v}:\,&&U&&\to \,&&\mathbb {F} \\&y&&\mapsto \,&&f(u,y)&&&&&&x&&\mapsto \,&&f(x,v)\\\end{alignedat}}$$
> Given $S\in {\mathcal {D}}^{\prime }(U)$ and $T\in {\mathcal {D}}^{\prime }(V)$, define the following functions:
> $${\begin{alignedat}{9}\langle S,f^{\bullet }\rangle :\,&V&&\to \,&&\mathbb {F} &&\quad {\text{ and }}\quad &&\langle T,f_{\bullet }\rangle :\,&&U&&\to \,&&\mathbb {F} \\&v&&\mapsto \,&&\langle S,f^{v}\rangle &&&&&&u&&\mapsto \,&&\langle T,f_{u}\rangle \\\end{alignedat}}$$
> where $\langle T,f_{\bullet }\rangle \in {\mathcal {D}}(U)$ and $\langle S,f^{\bullet }\rangle \in {\mathcal {D}}(V)$. These definitions associate every $S\in {\mathcal {D}}'(U)$ and $T\in {\mathcal {D}}'(V)$ with the (respective) continuous linear map:
> $${\begin{alignedat}{9}\,&{\mathcal {D}}(U\times V)&&\to \,&&{\mathcal {D}}(V)&&\quad {\text{ and }}\quad &&\,&&{\mathcal {D}}(U\times V)&&\to \,&&{\mathcal {D}}(U)\\&f&&\mapsto \,&&\langle S,f^{\bullet }\rangle &&&&&&f&&\mapsto \,&&\langle T,f_{\bullet }\rangle \\\end{alignedat}}$$
> Moreover if either $S$ (resp. $T$) has compact support then it also induces a continuous linear map of $C^{\infty }(U\times V)\to C^{\infty }(V)$ (resp. $C^{\infty }(U\times V)\to C^{\infty }(U)$).

> **Fubini's theorem for distributions**. Let ${\displaystyle S\in {\mathcal {D}}'(U)}$ and ${\displaystyle T\in {\mathcal {D}}'(V)}$. If ${\displaystyle f\in {\mathcal {D}}(U\times V)}$ then
> $\langle S,\langle T,f_{\bullet }\rangle \rangle =\langle T,\langle S,f^{\bullet }\rangle \rangle.$
> The tensor product of ${\displaystyle S\in {\mathcal {D}}'(U)}$ and $T\in {\mathcal {D}}'(V)$, denoted by $S\otimes T$ or $T\otimes S$ is the distribution in $U\times V$ defined by:
> $${\displaystyle (S\otimes T)(f):=\langle S,\langle T,f_{\bullet }\rangle \rangle =\langle T,\langle S,f^{\bullet }\rangle \rangle}$$

**Question**. Does that mean the tensor product is commutative? It's not true in general, though

Comment: From which Wikipedia article is that?

Comment: I read it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tensor_products_of_distributions

Comment: Is it "denoted by $S\otimes T$ or $T\otimes S$" that you interpret as tensor product being commutative?

Comment: Actually I was looking at the last line of "Fubini's Theorem" above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the tensor product of distributions is not commutative.

If we rewrite the last line with formal arguments we have
$$
\langle (S \otimes T)(x,y), f(x,y) \rangle
= \langle S(x), \langle T(y), f(x,y) \rangle \rangle
= \langle T(y), \langle S(x), f(x,y) \rangle \rangle
.
$$
Had the tensor product been commutative then the last expression would have read $\langle T(x), \langle S(y), f(x,y) \rangle \rangle$ or $\langle T(y), \langle S(x), f(y,x) \rangle \rangle$.